# Where does the value of process_id from catalog.executions come from?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-agent-job

I'm trying to link the execution of a catalog package to its caller, a job/step.

In the table `catalog.executions` exists the attribute `process_id`. The documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15 says that is

> the process ID of the external process, if applicable.

I'm wondering if this `int` is in any way related to the job or step that called the execution of the package, but I didn't find more information about it. I could not find any relation with any of the id's in `dbo.sysjobactivity`, `dbo.sysjobhistory` and alike.

Comment: I think process_id is the OS PID of the process so it's an ephemeral value, not something that's unique and can be used to link an execution instance.

Comment: What would be the purpose of having an ephemeral id?

Comment: I can't say the Windows process id is particularly useful. It's unique per host but a new one gets assigned each time a new process runs and the values are reused.